# How to prevent cascade soft-delete efcore asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-core-2.0

```
public class item{
   public int id{get;set;}
   public string name{get;set;}
}

public class SalesItem{
   public int id{get;set;}
   public string item_id{get;set;}   
   [ForeignKey(namof(item_id))]
   public virtual Item item{get;set;}
}
```

There are lots of classes where **item** is referenced as **foreignkey**. I need to restrict the item to delete ***(soft-delete)*** if that item is used in another table(referenced).

Comment: Use this `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);`

Comment: I couldnt understand this question, can you add some more description? Are you saying you want to soft-delete the parent and not soft-delete the child?

Comment: No it should restrict both parent and child . revert(restrict) the deletion of item, if its item id present in another table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);` for the entity in the `OnModelCreating`